# Bootstrap vs Angular 2: ERROR in multi script-loader! Module not found: Error: /~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I created a new Angular 2 project with ng new klw

1. I installed bootstrap: `npm install bootstrap@next`
2. added style and scripts into angular

   ```
   "styles": [
       "styles.css",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
     ],
     "scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
   "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
     ],
   ```
3. Integrated bootstrap 4 to `angular-cli: npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ngbootstrap`
4. added NgbModule import into **app.module.ts**
5. added to import section NgbModule into **app.module.ts**
6. **modified app.module.html** added: `<NgbAlert> Alert text </NgbAlert>`

Which was what I missed to do?

When I run ng serve I got the following ERRORS:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap relative to F:/src/prjs/angular2/pilot/klw/src/app/app.module.ts., resolving symbol AppModule in F:/src/prjs/angular2/pilot/klw/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in F:/src/prjs/angular2/pilot/klw/src/app/app.module.ts

ERROR in multi script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js script-loader!./~/tether/dist/js/tether.js script-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'F:\src\prjs\angular2\pilot\klw\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js' in 'F:\src\prjs\angular2\pilot\klw'
 @ multi script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js script-loader!./~/tether/dist/js/tether.js script-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js

ERROR in multi script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js script-loader!./~/tether/dist/js/tether.js script-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'F:\src\prjs\angular2\pilot\klw\node_modules\tether\dist\js\tether.js' in 'F:\src\prjs\angular2\pilot\klw'

ERROR in multi script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js script-loader!./~/tether/dist/js/tether.js script-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'F:\src\prjs\angular2\pilot\klw\node_modules\tether\dist\js\tether.js' in 'F:\src\prjs\angular2\pilot\klw'
 @ multi script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js script-loader!./~/tether/dist/js/tether.js script-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js

ERROR in multi script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js script-loader!./~/tether/dist/js/tether.js script-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'F:\src\prjs\angular2\pilot\klw\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js' in 'F:\src\prjs\angular2\pilot\klw'
 @ multi script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js script-loader!./~/tether/dist/js/tether.js script-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js

ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'F:\src\prjs\angular2\pilot\klw\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css' in 'F:\src\prjs\angular2\pilot\klw'
 @ multi ./src/styles.css ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

ERROR in F:/src/prjs/angular2/pilot/klw/src/app/app.module.ts (8,25): Cannot find module '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'.)

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' in 'F:\src\prjs\angular2\pilot\klw\src\app'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 15:0-55
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/ ./src/main.ts
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: I don't know why not found the tether, jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: further clarification of the following steps 2. :  I added style and scripts into angular, exactly into the angular-cli.json 3. : include imports into app.module.ts exactly: - top of file: import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' - into import section of @NgModule added NgbModule

Comment: How about using https://ng-bootstrap.github.io that provides native Angular 2 integration and doesn't require jQuery, tether nor any other external dependencies?

Comment: Hi, thank you of your comments!

Comment: What about Bootstrap 4 SASS install? Is it available to install without ruby?

Comment: you don't need SASS, Bootstrap 4 comes with pre-compiled CSS. But if you need to process SASS than yes, you can do it without ruby now on node.js (guess most people are using node.js to power their build tools those days).

Answer (score 2):

1. remove symbol ^ for @angular/cdk and @angular/material in package.json
2. remove node_modules and package-lock.json
3. npm cache clean -f
4. npm i

It works in my case. Hope it helps you

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I skipped step 1 as I wasn't using these dependencies. Ran like clockwork next time I ran `ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But I have solved it.
Main error is in the scripts and css which are coming from the 'node_modules' folder.
Go to '.angular-cli.json' file and delete all 'node_modules' files and manually type the path of your all SCRIPTS and CSS ..

Thanks

Comment: Go to 'angular-cli.json' file an delete all 'node_modules' files? what difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@next
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but fixed.
Please check inside .angular-cli.json all the linked scripts files are available or not. if any one script file is not available the @ multi script-loader error will come. Properly link all the script path.
Please check here:https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5665#issuecomment-452282834